# Through-hole LED package identification

Tags: led, identification, packages, through-hole

I am looking for a way to search for a replacement LED.
Unfortunately I don't know the name of the package.

The LED has a kind of conical recess at its tip to diffuse the light sideways instead of axially.

I am missing the technical name for that specific tip. Therefore I have difficulties to search the manufacturer's websites for that specificity.

What is the official name of that kind of tip?

[image: Led package]

Answer (score 0):

I think it is called a "dimple lens" LED but I'm not certain.

https://www.lumex.com/spec/SSL-LX304F4GTD.pdf

For a quick and dirty replacement you could take a flat top LED (or flatten a round one with sandpaper) and drill the dimple in it using a drill bit of larger diameter than the LED...